# Problema con consulta SQLite

Tags: sql, sqllite

la consulta que quiero realizar es sobre la selección de un tema musical con ciertas especificaciones, para realizar una lista de reproducción, La misma se genera a medida que se reproducen los temas, La consulta es algo así como seleccionar la próxima canción. En la tabla tengo un dato lógico como, "reproducido" donde se vuelca a true cuando este se reproduce y "ultimareproduccion" donde se coloca el DATETIME en el momento de la reproducción. A continuación el esquema de la base de datos:

Tabla albums

```
CREATE TABLE "albums" ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `nombre` TEXT );
```

Tabla musica

```
CREATE TABLE "musica" ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, `nombreyruta` TEXT NOT NULL, `anulado` NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `album` INTEGER, `reproducido` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `ultimareproduccion` TEXT );
```

Tabla reproduccion

```
CREATE TABLE "reproduccion" ( `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, `idalbum` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `habilitado` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 )
```

Necesitaría que en la selección del próximo tema, se base en una consulta SELECT, que elija el próximo tema a reproducir de la siguiente forma, Que tenga los datos REPRODUCCION = 0, y que evite seleccionar los que se hallan reproducido hace poco tiempo, y ademas, que dentro de esto en un porcentaje se puede realizar un Ramdom, o selección aleatoria. Un ejemplo, Se solicita el tema de reproducción que ordenado de mayor a menor en "ULTIMAREPRODUCCION" y que del 40% de estos mas viejos, se pueda seleccionar aleatoriamente.
La idea principalmente es que la lista de reproducción no sea repetitiva es decir, que no sea la lista siempre igual, y que las canciones no se escuchen una seguida de la otra.

Aqui dejo el select que yo tengo a previas, lo que hace es seleccionar todos los temas que se puedan elegir para su reproduccion:

```
SELECT musica.id from musica inner join reproduccion on musica.album = reproduccion.idalbum  WHERE musica.reproducido = 0;
```

Como se puede ver, la reproducción no se lleva en la base de datos, sino que se realiza cuando se pregunta con un SELECT cual es la siguiente canción a reproducir. que es lo que haría falta para resolver esta pregunta!

Espero que puedan ayudarme muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Porqué `ultimareproduccion` en la tabla `musica` es de tipo `TEXT`? ¿No debería ser de tipo `DATETIME`?

Comment: En sqllite el date time se usan funciones, y el tipo se coloca text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para calcular el 40% de las canciones almacenadas en la tabla `musica` podemos usar `COUNT(*)` y multiplicarlo por el valor deseado (0.4 para el 40%):

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 0.4 AS int) FROM musica
```

Como el resultado es un número de coma flotante hay que convertirlo a entero con un [`CAST`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr).

Ese resultado se puede usar en la cláusula SQL `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM musica m
ORDER BY ultimareproduccion DESC
LIMIT (
  SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 0.4 AS int) + 1 FROM musica
)
```

He sumado 1 al cálculo del 40% para redondear hacia arriba y evitar que no se obtenga ningún registro cuando vale 0.

Ahora podemos usar `ORDER RANDOM()` para desordenar ese 40% de registros obtenidos.

La función [`random()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) devuelve valores al azar por cada registro seleccionado anteriormente, así que los registros serán reordenados de acuerdo a ese valor aleatorio.

Por último sólo resta quedarnos con uno de ellos con `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM musica m
  ORDER BY ultimareproduccion DESC
  LIMIT (
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) * 0.4 AS int) + 1 FROM musica
  )
) c
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Ejemplo en línea del SQL propuesto: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3quzKL3kjJ7MGjY2FKCksJ/0